# Is it possible to integrate OpenSea SDK into Kotlin Android App?

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, blockchain, nft

Here is the link to a documentation: https://projectopensea.github.io/opensea-js/

Is it possible to integrate it into a Kotlin App, and make every user able to create their own NFT from their account within my app?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: hello have you found a solution? looking for answers to same question